# Django Admin: How to display more fields as links?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, hyperlink, django-admin

The default admin page for Django automatically makes the first heading of each table a link to edit the information (see below):

[image]

Clicking the `ID` column data will take you to a page to edit the fields in the selected table, in this case `Applicants`

Is there a way of changing this setup, so that `Surname` is the link to edit and not `ID`?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [list_displays_links](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links)  to control if and which fields in `list_display` should be linked to the edit page for an object.

Example usage:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'surname', 'location')
    list_display_links = ('first_name', 'surname')
```

...would make both `first_name` and `surname` clickable.

Answer (score 2):

based on [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links):

> By default, the change list page will link the first column – the first field specified in list_display – to the change page for each item. But list_display_links lets you change this:
>
> - Set it to None to get no links at all.
> - Set it to a list or tuple of fields (in the same format as list_display) whose columns you want converted to links.

```
class ApplicantsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'first_name', 'surname', 'location', 'job') #fields that you want to display
    list_display_links = ('surname',)
```

you should select `list_display_links` from fields of `list_display` tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, if `'surname'` is not assigned to [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) but assigned to [list_display_links](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links) as shown below:

```py
class ApplicantsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id', 
        'first_name', 
        # 'surname', # Here
        'location', 
        'job'
    )                     # Here
    list_display_links = ('surname',)
```

You will get the error below:

> ERRORS: <class 'xxx.admin.Applicant'>: (admin.E111) The value of
> 'list_display_links[2]' refers to 'surname', which is not defined
> in 'list_display'.

So, `'surname'` must be assigned to both `list_display` and `list_display_links` as shown below:

```py
class ApplicantsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id', 
        'first_name', 
        'surname', # Here
        'location', 
        'job'
    )                     # Here
    list_display_links = ('surname',)
```